# Joining in SQLite to get desired records

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, relational-database

I am working on a mobile application which takes two inputs - Source Station Name and Destination Station Names. Upon receiving these two inputs, the application would then enlist the names of trains available for the given stations along with their source_arrival and destination_reach timings.

(**Note**: For now, I am only focusing on the unreserved local trains that operate in the state of West Bengal, India)

I am using **SQLite** as the RDBMS. I have following three tables as the sources of the data -

- **train_table** (which has the details of the trains available):
  [image]
- **station_table** (which contains the details of the stations): 
  [image]
- **route_table** (which contains the route details): 
  [image]

Now, my aim is to produce the output in the following manner as specified earlier (suppose I gave **Baruipur Jn** as source and **Sealdah** as destination):

[image]

I am unable to figure out the query needed for this. Initially, I was trying something like the following:

```sql
    select r1.trainId, r1.arrival as SrcArrive, r2.arrival 
    as Reach  from route_table r1 cross join route_table r2 
    where r1.trainId = r2.trainId and r1.stationId <> r2.stationId and 
    r1.arrival <> r2.arrival;
```

(Yes, without the **trainName**)

But I was unable to cut down the unintended source_arrival timings. However, I was able to retrieve the number of different trains available for given two stations with the following:

```sql
    select _id, trainNO, trainName from train_table where _id in 
    (select trainId from route_table where stationId = 109 
    INTERSECT 
    select trainId from route_table where stationId = 21);
```

But with this, I am not able to get to the final result that I need.

Comment: The `route_table` structure is not what I would expect to see for a train route (anywhere in the world!). I would expect the `route_table` rows displayed here to all have the same `_id`, because a route defines a train and all the station stops. Then (in the first example) the cross join would be `on r1._id = r2.id`. Side note: `r1.arrival` should be strictly less than `r2.arrival`.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Show what relevant queries you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: I think I provided the desired output and the major queries I tried. I tried to put the tables in forms of ASCII MySQL style tables but could not get them rendered here.

Comment: Re images: cut from your source or after free online OCR, paste into a code block. Give DDL & table initialization code--hopefully tabular. I explained why. PS "list" not "enlist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, try once.

```
select routeData.*, train_table.* from (select r1.trainId, r1.arrival as SrcArrive, r2.arrival 
as Reach  from route_table r1 cross join route_table r2 
where r1.trainId = r2.trainId and r1.stationId <> r2.stationId and 
r1.arrival <> r2.arrival) routeData inner join train_table on routeData.trainId=train_table._id;
```

I have redifined the selection from route table, try this updated one:

```
select trainName, SrcArrival, Destination from (select trainData.trainName, route.* from 
(select A.trainId, A.arrival as SrcArrival, B.trainId, B.arrival as Destination from 
route_table A inner join route_table B on A.trainId=B.trainId where A.stationId=109 and 
B.stationId=259 and A.arrival<B.arrival) route inner join train_table trainData on 
route.trainId=trainData._id) order by SrcArrival, Destination;
```